# How to lock a GIT repository via GIT API

Tags: git, bitbucket

How to lock a GIT repository via GIT API?

I know manual way is to select Branch permissions > Add permissions > select Branch, and click Prevent All changes. We need an API which will help us with this step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see [branch-related API here](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/search?q=branch)

That includes [`repositories / {username} / {repo_slug} / branch-restrictions`](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/branch-restrictions#post), which has a POST method, to create a new branch restriction rule for a repository.

That can be a good start, provided your [BitBucket server](https://bitbucket.org/product/) does support that endpoint.

As [Jim Redmond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5054717/jim-redmond) (from Atlassian) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119622/how-to-lock-a-git-repository-via-git-api/56120268?noredirect=1#comment98879004_56120268):

> The Bitbucket Server (self-hosted, not `api.bitbucket.org`) equivalent is:
>   "[REST Resources Provided By: Bitbucket Server - Ref Restriction](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.0.1/bitbucket-ref-restriction-rest.html)".

Comment: The Bitbucket Server (self-hosted, not api.bitbucket.org) equivalent is https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.0.1/bitbucket-ref-restriction-rest.html

Comment: @JimRedmond Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.